# Wrong followers number

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using tweepy and I count the number of followers like that :

```
i = 0
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
    followers_results[follower.id] = follower.screen_name
    i += 1
print(i)
```

But I obtain a different result if I do that :

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('key', 'consumer_secret')
auth.set_access_token('access_token', 'access_token_secret')
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
user = api.get_user('username')
print (user.followers_count)
```

It seems the 2nd method gives the real number of followers (according to my account page on twitter) and the 1st always gives "number of followers - 3".

Why both method don't give the same result ? And which one should I trust ?

Comment: I have a feeling this is due to the ordering of json/dictionaries being variable. The +3 is possibly coincidental, a different computer might have a different, or inconsistent, factor

Comment: Could this be private accounts you don't have the ability to see knocking the totals off?

Comment: @asongtoruin that could makes sence ! Do you know a way to check if an account is private or not using tweepy ?